# How to avoid Crystal 2008 losing data sources?

Tags: datasource, crystal-reports-2008

We do a lot of work with Crystal reports in IDE CR Developer version 12.5.0.1190

We have numerous SQL Server databases (testing, training, production, etc.) and so often have to change data source location.  Frequently, I find that one of the sources is no longer available and I have to create it again.

It seems to be related to the .rpt files themselves--open a different file and have no problem.

How can this be prevented, and is there a way to have all the files tap into the same source?  (When I create one, I find that I can use it for some time on multiple files, even after some of the files no longer show it as an option.)

The sources are definitely not in DSNs.  I try to avoid those--apparently successfully, as none exist on my local drive right now! :-)

Comment: Surprising lack of interest....
Guess I'll just hope 2011 fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you please let me know if there is a reason you are choosing to avoid DSNs? Would an answer that used DSN's be acceptable?

Comment: If the solution depends on a DSN, then I have to ensure the DSN gets installed on seven thousand desktops and at least a dozen Citrix servers.  And even if they are in DSNs, there's still the issue of having them disappear.

Comment: I frequently used Crystal Reports XI R2 (the major version prior to 2008) and primarily used system DSNs, and I have never experienced the symptom you mentioned. Indeed DSNs seem to be designed to allow multiple clients to "tap into the same source".

Have you tried leaving the datasource on the reports the same, and instead changing the connection back and forth at the user's system level? This seems just as (in)convenient as doing it in Crystal's interface

Comment: Even if the users had the ability to change datasource location (they don't), asking seven thousand doctors, nurses, cooks, clerks, and janitors to do that would require us to hire a hundred more people for the help desk.  (AAking them to install DSNs would be equally counterproductive.)

Comment: @Bohemian.. why my answer was deleted?